# Redemption nag screen keeps coming up

Tags: outlook-redemption

Under win XP, the 'nag screen' showed up only when installing redemption.dll. Under win7 and win8 I get it whenever I log on. Is this normal?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is normal. Redemption stores the information when it last displayed its EULA differently on different operating systems.

Note that the distributable version of Redemption never displays any prompts. Also note that the eval version of Redemption is not licensed for any business related purposes.